# Youtube search command for discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Simple. I am making a youtube search command for discord using python
This is the code:

```
async def youtube(ctx, *, search):
    query_string = urllib.parse.urlencode({
        'search_query': search
    })
    htm_content = urllib.request.urlopen(
        'http://www.youtube.com/results?' + query_string
    )
    search_results = re.findall('href=\"\\/watch\\?v=(.{11})', htm_content.read().decode())
    await ctx.send('http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' + search_results[0])
```

The error that I am having is this:

```
Ignoring exception in command youtube:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ryzen\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 83, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Ryzen\Desktop\ae\bot\bot 2.0\bot.py", line 738, in youtube
    await ctx.send('http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' + search_results[0])
IndexError: list index out of range

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ryzen\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 892, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\Ryzen\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 797, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Ryzen\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 92, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: IndexError: list index out of range
```

Thanks

Comment: `...m/watch?v=' + search_results[0]` maybe the list is empty and there's no 0 index.?

Comment: Nimeshka is correct. On top of that you are using asyncio so you should use [aiohttp](https://pypi.org/project/aiohttp/).

Answer (score 0):

Nimeshka is correct, whatever you're using to fill that `search_results` list is failing to find anything.

There are a few things you can do to help debug. Firstly, try capturing the contents of `htm_content.read().decode()` into a file to see what you're getting. There is a very good chance you're being served a capcha, error, or other something you can't use because you are not sending a User-Agent with your request.

Assuming that you do get the DOM response you want, having a copy in a file can help you more accurately write your regex. That in addition with online tools such as regexr or regex101 for testing/debugging will help more. And then using `r"strings"` means you can copy the regex directly without needing to duplicate every backslash.

```
BASE = "https://youtube.com/results"

async def youtube(ctx, *, search):
    p = {"search_query": search}
    # Spoof a user agent header or the request will immediately fail
    h = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0"}
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as client:
        async with client.get(BASE, params=p, headers=h) as resp:
            dom = await resp.text()
            # open("debug.html", "w").write(dom)
    found = re.findall(r'href"\/watch\?v=([a-zA-Z0-9_-]{11})', dom)
    return f"https://youtu.be/{found[0]}"
```

One last word of warning, Google tends to serve advertisements in place of top results, so just bare in mind what your regex is *actually* returning ;)

---

Alternatively, I would suggest setting up a new developer project with [Google's APIs](https://console.developers.google.com/), as this will allow you to skip the webscraping part all together and use an API client instead. Using pip installs for `google-api-python-client`:

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

def get_service():
    # Get developer key from "credentials" tab of api dashboard
    return build("youtube", "v3", developerKey="key")

def search(term, channel):
    service = get_service()
    resp = service.search().list(
        part="id",
        q=term,
        # safeSearch="none" if channel.is_nsfw() else "moderate",
        videoDimension="2d",
    ).execute()
    return resp["items"][0]["id"]["videoId"]
```

[API documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it changing the regular expression line to this:

```
re.findall( r"watch\?v=(\S{11})", html_content.read().decode())
```

After that, it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Let´s take a look to this part:

```
search_results = re.findall('href=\"\\/watch\\?v=(.{11})', htm_content.read().decode())
await ctx.send('http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' + search_results[0])
```

I solve this making a variable for the `search_content` to see all the html page.

```
search_content= html_content.read().decode()
```

Then I try to find this pattern in the html content

```
search_results = re.findall(r'\/watch\?v=\w+', search_content)
```

Now your bot can send the first result to the discord server.

This pattern find the `\/watch\?v=` part and then capture the next caracters whith `\w+`. After this caracters there is a ' so the `re.findall` process break the capture

---

Here is the full code:

```
@bot.command()
async def youtube(ctx, *, search):
    query_string = parse.urlencode({'search_query': search})
    html_content = request.urlopen('http://www.youtube.com/results?' + query_string)
    search_content= html_content.read().decode()
    search_results = re.findall(r'\/watch\?v=\w+', search_content)
    #print(search_results)
    await ctx.send('https://www.youtube.com' + search_results[0])
```

I found a very interesting page where you can debug the regex and find patters in a text. This tool help me to solve this problem: [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/)

I hope this post can help you

Answer (score 0):

The code that you gave was almost entirely correct there was 2 things that need changing parse.urlencode and request.urlopen.
First of all for this to work you need urllib installed so go into cmd and install it:

> pip install urllib

then you need to import urllib so you do:

> import urllib.parse

then you also need to import urlencode so type in:

> from urllib.parse import urlencode

also install and import parse so go to cmd and do:

> pip install parse

and then import it into your code

> import parse

when you install and import those you can copy/pase this code and it should work for you:

```
    @client.command(aliases=['youtube','yt'])
async def _youtube(ctx, *, search):
    author=ctx.message.author
    guild=ctx.guild
    query_string = urllib.parse.urlencode({'search_query': search})
    html_content = urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.youtube.com/results?' + query_string)
    search_content= html_content.read().decode()
    search_results = re.findall(r'\/watch\?v=\w+', search_content)
    #print(search_results)
    await ctx.send(f'{author.mention} Here is the search result:\n https://www.youtube.com' + search_results[0])
```